# Preload images for smooth transition

Tags: android, android-studio

Suppose I have an imageview and I want to swap two images on each click. It works quite laggy for the first swap because next image has to load itselft to stack(following swaps are okay). Is there any way I preload both images to get the smooth transition from the very first swap?

Comment: You could use a service or background task to load your images.

Comment: maybe you can use two imageView and put on same position and then when swap image u use animation to make smooth transition?